# Getting error in passing date value in ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, date, http-post

I am trying to pass a Datein ajax request here is my ajax call
I am getting value of Date**06/13/2017**

```
$("#txtpdate").on("changeDate", function (e) {
            var Date = $('#txtpdate').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: false,
                async: false,
                url: '/api/ServiceProvider/GetUpdatedPrice/' + Date,
                cache: false
            }).done(function (response) {



            });
```

and here is my controller

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("GetUpdatedPrice/{Date}")]
        public async Task<ServiceProviderDocuments> GetUpdatedPrice(DateTime Date)
        {
            return await ServiceProviderDocumentsGateway.GetUpdatedPriceofBike(date);

        }
```

but i am getting this error

```
**http://localhost:54850/api/ServiceProvider/GetUpdatedPrice/06/13/2017 404 (Not Found)**
```

does I have to pass date in JSON format or any other thing i am missing ?
please help.

Comment: this is becouse the date has slash, like path slash, try to url encode the value

Comment: Chage your route's annotation so that it can accept a slashed value for `Date`. On a side note, don't use `async: false`.

Comment: i am getting value like this 06/06/2017

Comment: can you tell what is the exact Url format of a working API URL?

Answer (score 0):

The `/` symbol in your date value is interpreted as a URL path segments delimiter. Use `data` field to send any value to your action. For example use

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  contentType: false,
  async: false,
  url: '/api/ServiceProvider/GetUpdatedPrice/',
  data: {Date: DateValue}
});
```

See [jQuery.ajax() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp) for details.

Answer (score 0):

this is happend because date formated in dd/mm/y in / formate

```
$("#txtpdate").on("changeDate", function (e) {
            var Date = $('#txtpdate').val();
            var newdate = Date.replace("/", "_");

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: false,
                async: false,
                url: '/api/ServiceProvider/GetUpdatedPrice/' + newdate,
                cache: false
            }).done(function (response) {



            });


            [HttpPost]
        [Route("GetUpdatedPrice/{Date}")]
        public async Task<ServiceProviderDocuments> GetUpdatedPrice(DateTime Date)
        {

    //  again replace date from '_' to '/'

            return await ServiceProviderDocumentsGateway.GetUpdatedPriceofBike(date);

        }
```